# How do I get all the lastest rows from a table based on the contents of two columns?

Tags: mysql

**messages table**

```
id (int)
recipient_id (int)
sender_id (int)
content (text)
created (datetime)
```

What I'm trying to do is get the latest message from every conversation that a user has had with other users.

Let's say i'm trying to find them for user_id = 3, this is what I have so far. It's not a great solution and feels a bit like a hack but it is working.

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT MAX(id) FROM messages 
     WHERE `recipient_id` = 3 OR `sender_id` = 3
     GROUP BY (recipient_id + sender_id))
ORDER BY created DESC
```

Comment: GROUP BY sender_id AND ORDER BY id DESC

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY recipient_id, sender_id.

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE id IN
    (SELECT MAX(id) FROM messages 
     WHERE `recipient_id` = 3 OR `sender_id` = 3
     GROUP BY recipient_id, sender_id)
ORDER BY created DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

let me clear first your question ?

1. you need latest message from every conversation ?

after see your query i suggest you use this

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE `recipient_id` = 3 OR `sender_id` = 3
GROUP BY (recipient_id + sender_id)) ORDER BY created DESC limit 1
```

it give you latest message

the reason why i give limit 1 based on your question ? **Latest** but if you need all from latest message till first just remove `limit 1` from that query